# If $(R,H)$ is a von Neumann algebra, then what is the expectation functional by a vector $x \in H$?

Tags: terminology, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $(R,H)$ be a von Neumann algebra. Let $\rho$ be a state on $R$.

In the abstract of [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102913224) the author says

> ... the expection value by the vector $\sigma_{\psi}(\rho)$ is $\rho$.

Now I was wondering what this meant. My guess is that we have
\begin{equation}
 \rho(r) = \langle r \cdot \sigma_{\psi}(\rho), \sigma_{\psi}(\rho) \rangle_{H},
\end{equation}
for all $r \in R$. Is this correct? I have tried looking further into the paper, but I was unable to verify my guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it means exactly what you wrote. The name comes from [Quantum Mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation_value_(quantum_mechanics)).